# Breaking out of a docker container

Tags: security, docker

Are there any security risks with allowing users to run `docker` and mount files he has access to?

We have shared network mount where all users home directories reside and we basically don't want `user1` whose home directory is in `/app/mount/user1/` to be able to somehow get access to `/app/mount/user2/`.

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.docker.com/articles/security/:

"This daemon currently requires root privileges, and you should therefore be aware of some important details.

First of all, only trusted users should be allowed to control your Docker daemon. This is a direct consequence of some powerful Docker features. Specifically, Docker allows you to share a directory between the Docker host and a guest container; and it allows you to do so without limiting the access rights of the container."